# SPOJ Problem Flibonakki time limit exceed

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am trying to solve this [problem](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FLIB/) in Haskell but getting time limit exceed. I applied all my Haskell and mathematical skill to optimize this but all in vain. Could some one please suggest me how to optimize this code further. The sequence  F_3 + F_7 + F_11 .... + F_(4n+3) = F_2n*F_(2n+1). I used O(log n) to method to calculate the Fibonacci numbers.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS

matmul :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]
matmul [a,b,c] [d,e,f] m = [x,y,z] where
    y = (a*e + b*f) `mod` m
    z = (b*e + c*f) `mod` m
    x = y + z


powM ::[Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
powM a n m | n == 1 = a 
   | n == 2 = matmul a a m
   | even n = powM ( matmul a a m ) ( div n 2 ) m 
   | otherwise = matmul a ( powM ( matmul a a m ) ( div n 2 ) m ) m 

readInt :: BS.ByteString -> Integer
readInt  = fst.fromJust.BS.readInteger 

solve::Integer -> BS.ByteString
solve n = BS.pack.show $ mod ( c*d ) 1000000007 where 
 [c,d,_] = powM [1,1,0] ( 2*n ) 1000000007
--([_,a,_]:_) = powM [[1,2,1],[0,5,3],[0,3,2]] n 1000000007
-- f_3+f_7+f_11+f_15 = f_2n*f_(2n+1)

main = BS.interact $ BS.unlines. map ( solve.readInt ) . tail . BS.lines
```

Comment: When you use time profiling, what functions are taking the most time?http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html#id677833

Comment: No one has solved this in haskell, may be its too slow for this question.

Comment: Perhaps a bit of memoization would help.

Comment: Another suggestion: using `Word64` or `Int64` instead of `Integer` will probably make a huge difference.

Comment: @Daniel Wangner Thank you. It was really helpful but i think the problem is with stack space. For 2^51 i got Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes for compiled code so  i think same with SPOJ how ever on ghci prompt , running solve (2^51 ) does not complain such thing. It seems logic_max is correct.

Comment: For stack overflows, a bit of strictness annotation is usually the solution.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with Haskell but with ghc-6.10, which is the version used by SPOJ.  I can't replicate a stack overflow with ghc-6.12.3, which is the oldest Haskell I have available, but it is considerably slower than ghc-7.  You can try adding bang patterns to the list patterns in `matmul`, which is probably where the thunk is building up.

Comment: you can also use http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci-Folge#Formel_von_Moivre-Binet for calculation of F(4n-1) but watch out - this is a mathematical formula maybe it's not working in computer arithmatics due to rounding error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solving seems to be fast enough but it seems that your main function does not print the answer after each new line. In fact it requires an extra newline to get the last answer so this can be the cause of your timeout! Here is a version that prints each answer directly after the input.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
import qualified Text.Show.ByteString as BS

matmul :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]
matmul [a,b,c] [d,e,f] m = [x,y,z] where
    y = (a*e + b*f) `mod` m
    z = (b*e + c*f) `mod` m
    x = y + z

powM :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
powM a n m | n == 1 = a 
   | n == 2 = matmul a a m
   | even n = powM ( matmul a a m ) ( div n 2 ) m 
   | otherwise = matmul a ( powM ( matmul a a m ) ( div n 2 ) m ) m 

solve :: Integer -> Integer
solve n = mod ( c*d ) 1000000007 
  where 
  [c,d,_] = powM [1,1,0] ( 2*n ) 1000000007

readInteger :: B.ByteString -> Integer
readInteger  = fst . fromJust . B.readInteger

readInt :: B.ByteString -> Int
readInt = fst . fromJust . B.readInt

get :: IO B.ByteString
get = liftM (B.fromChunks . (:[])) BC.getLine

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- liftM readInt get
  replicateM_ n ( liftM readInteger get >>= B.putStrLn . BS.show . solve )
```